# ApexChart does not change colors correctly when you change the theme.mode property

Tags: angular, ng-apexcharts

I am using Tailwind and I created a service to check if the page is in dark or light mode. The service works fine, so I try to use it to change the property theme.mode of chartOptions.

I am using Lodash.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.themeService.themeChange.subscribe((isDarkTheme) => {
        if (isDarkTheme) {
            const theme = this.chartOptions.theme;
            this.chartOptions = {
                ...this.chartOptions,
                theme: {
                    ...theme,
                    mode: 'dark',
                },
            };                
        } else {
            const theme = this.chartOptions.theme;
            this.chartOptions = {
                ...this.chartOptions,
                theme: {
                    ...theme,
                    mode: 'light',
                },
            };       
        }
        console.log(this.chartOptions);
    });
}
```

If I start on light mode, the colors are good and if I change to dark mode, the colors change perfectly, but the problems occur when I change to light mode again. The property fill of the tag text on the y-axis remains a light color, so it disappears because in light mode the background is white.

I do not have any style property. This is my chartOptions :

```
this.chartOptions = {
      series: [
        {
          name: "distibuted",
          data: [21, 22, 10, 28, 16, 21, 13, 30]
        }
      ],
      chart: {
        height: 350,
        type: "bar",
        events: {
          click: function(chart, w, e) {
            // console.log(chart, w, e)
          }
        }
      },
      theme: { 
        mode: 'light'
      },
      colors: [
        "#008FFB",
        "#00E396",
        "#FEB019",
        "#FF4560",
        "#775DD0",
        "#546E7A",
        "#26a69a",
        "#D10CE8"
      ],
      plotOptions: {
        bar: {
          columnWidth: "45%",
          distributed: true
        }
      },
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      },
      legend: {
        show: false
      },
      grid: {
        show: false
      },
      xaxis: {
        categories: [
          ["John", "Doe"],
          ["Joe", "Smith"],
          ["Jake", "Williams"],
          "Amber",
          ["Peter", "Brown"],
          ["Mary", "Evans"],
          ["David", "Wilson"],
          ["Lily", "Roberts"]
        ],
        labels: {
          style: {
            colors: [
              "#008FFB",
              "#00E396",
              "#FEB019",
              "#FF4560",
              "#775DD0",
              "#546E7A",
              "#26a69a",
              "#D10CE8"
            ],
            fontSize: "12px"
          }
        }
      }
    };
```

I am using Firefox and Angular 15.

I was just trying to search for information on the web, but nothing was related to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

```
// Initial init

            var style = getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('--bs-primary');
            var border = getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('--bs-border-color');
            var altrow = getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('--bs-table-striped-bg');

            var options = {
            //whatever your options are...,
                colors: [style],
                grid: {
                    borderColor: border,
                    row: {
                        colors: [altrow, 'transparent'], // takes an array which will be repeated on columns
                        opacity:0.5
                    },
                }
            };

            var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#annual-results-average-chart"), options);

            chart.render();

// On theme change (from dark to light or light to dark)

            var handlerId = KTThemeMode.on("kt.thememode.change", function() {
 // Get the new colors...
                var style = getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('--bs-primary');
                var border = getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('--bs-border-color');
                var altrow = getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('--bs-table-striped-bg');

 // Put the new colors into an updated options array...
                var updatedOptions = {
                    colors: [style],
                    grid: {
                        borderColor: border,
                        row: {
                            colors: [altrow, 'transparent'], // takes an array which will be repeated on columns
                            opacity:0.5
                        },
                    },
                };

 // Update the chart with the new options...
                chart.updateOptions(updatedOptions);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this css for dark theme:

```
/* Media query for dark mode */
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  .dark-mode .apexcharts-text {
    fill: #fff;
  }
  .dark-mode .apexcharts-tooltip,
  .dark-mode .apexcharts-tooltip-title {
    background-color: #333 !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    border: 1px solid #555 !important;
  }
  .dark-mode .apexcharts-legend-text {
    color: #fff !important;
    border: 1px solid #555 !important;
  }
}
```